# Is there a keyword to match array elements in javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, matching

Is there a javascript keyword to compare two array elements? 
For example:

```
var a = [1,2,3];
var b = [4,2,5];
var c = a.keyword(b) = [0,1,0]
```

Comment: `0` means `false` and `1` means `true`? to answer the question: No, there is no method for it.

Comment: could you please elaborate on what this function is supposed to do? compare the two Arrays index by index and return wether the items are identical? or count the occurances? map wether `b` contains the particular item from `a`, ...

Comment: @Thomas i think it's just `a[i] === b[i] ? 1 : 0`

Comment: What is the expected result for arrays of different lengths?

Comment: @nem035, but it could as well be `a.map(v => b.includes(v)? 1: 0)` or  `a.map(v => b.filter(w => v === w).length)` or even something completely different.

Comment: @Thomas yup, you're right. Thing is we're not only looking at the result example because OP also said "compare two array elements", which hints at an equality check.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [Array.prototype.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map?v=control) and compare the values to a second array using indexes.

```js
var a = [1,2,3];
var b = [4,2,5];
var c = a.map(function(elem, index){
  return elem === b[index];
});
console.log(c);
```

Comment: Thank you, so much easier than loops.

Comment: Of course! As an aside, this was just a rough sketch, you'll likely want additional logic if that function is going to be re-used. For example, this fails if the arrays are of different length (depending on your context, same length arrays might be guaranteed). [here](https://jsfiddle.net/ghdyhxwr/1/) is a jsfiddle demonstrating how you could additionally add some "safety checks".

Answer (score 0):

You could compare the elements at the same index and return `1` or zero, if found or not.

```js
var a = [1, 2, 3],
    b = [4, 2, 5];
    result = a.map(function (a, i) {
        return +(a === b[i]);
    });

console.log(result);
```

ES6

```js
var a = [1, 2, 3],
    b = [4, 2, 5];
    result = a.map((a, i) => +(a === b[i]));

console.log(result);
```